# Is there any function to upload instagram stories from React Native?

Tags: react-native, instagram

I have a react native app and I want to enable users to share videos and images as stories on instagram my from my app.

Comment: Hey, have you found something?

Comment: Hi yes. I was able to do that. from this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

Comment: You will have to write separate code for android and ios and bridge them with react native. Let me know if you have any problem

Comment: @salmanbukhari, can u help me with this

Comment: @ApurvaAggarwal sure, what are you having trouble with?